# Want to connect PHP5 to MS SQL SERVER 2005

Tags: php, sql-server-2005

I have an application that I made with PHP and MSSQL2000, but now want to connect it to a MSSQL2005 database. It's always failing and after doing some research I was told to download the `ntwdblib.dll` and replace the old one in my PHP directory which I did, but still cannot connect to it. I also uncommented the MSSQL extensions in my php.ini file.

Please can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Did you restart Apache after making the DLL and php.ini changes?

Comment: can you post the error codes or error messages too

Comment: @KoolKabin this is the error...Warning:mssql_connect() [function.mssql-connect]:Unable to connect to server:localhost in c:\wamp\www\new\connection.php on line 3

Comment: @bsanneh, read my <Edit>

Comment: @AlexanderMP yes TCP/IP is enabled

Comment: Maybe you are running a named instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you very much for your help.
Actually i did find out a way of making it work
First of all let me start with what i have compared to the system requirements
**MY SYSTEM**
OS:-Win xP SP2
PHP :- 5.3.5
MSSQL 2005
SQL Native client 2005

**Required**

Recommended :-Win xP SP3
PHP :- 5.2.4 or later
MSSQL Server 2008 Native Client (on the same computer php is running)
SQL Server Driver For PHP

after upgrading my windows to service pack 3 i then downloaded and installed the MSSQL Server 2008 Native Client
then installed the SQL Server Driver For PHP 2.0 which ask for a directory to save the dll files.
I browse to the php directory and then the 'ext' folder where it copied the dll files to.
Then went to the php.ini file and add these two  lines under the Dynamic Extensions.

extension=php_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc6.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc6.dll

Then restart my webserver and booommm....i got it working..
did a test connection to the database and it was succesfull..

Hope this will help others and thank you all for your assistance really appreciate it..
Peace

Answer (score 1):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mssql.installation.php

> The MSSQL extension is enabled by
>   adding extension=php_mssql.dll to
>   php.ini.
>        To get these functions to work, you have to compile PHP with
>   --with-mssql[=DIR] , where DIR is the FreeTDS install prefix. And FreeTDS
>   should be compiled using
>   --enable-msdblib .

also

> MS SQL functions are aliases to [Sybase](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sybase.php) functions if PHP is compiled with Sybase extension and without MS SQL extension.

**<Edit>**
Just asking. Do you have a `mssql_connect` function? Or does the connect fail? If the connection fails, be sure to enable TCP/IP in MSSQL (using SQL Server Configuration Manager). And I also recalled enabling Named Pipes, but I'm not sure it's needed.
**</Edit>**

As an alternative you could look at [COM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.com.php) and ADODB.

Example of COM and ADODB, connecting to SQL Server using Windows Authentication:

```
    $this->m_conn = new COM("ADODB.Connection");
    $this->m_conn->CommandTimeout=1200;
    $dsn="Provider=SQLNCLI;Data Source=server_name;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=database_name;Application Name=YourAppName - ".$user['name'];
    $this->m_conn->Open($dsn);
    if(!$this->m_conn)
        throw new Exception("Could not start ADO",101);
    $this->m_comm = new COM("ADODB.Command");
    $this->m_comm->ActiveConnection=$this->m_conn;
    $this->m_comm->CommandTimeout=1200;
```

Then execute a command

```
    $this->m_comm->CommandText=$sql;
    $res=$this->m_comm->Execute();
```

Then extract the data

```
    if(($num_cols=$res->Fields->Count())>=1)
    {
        $return=array();
        while(!$res->EOF)
        {
            $row=array();
            for($i=0;$i<$num_cols;$i++)
                $row[$res->Fields($i)->name]=$res->Fields($i)->value;
            $res->MoveNext();
            $return[]=$row;
        }
    }

    $res->Close();
    return $return;
```

Not sure about speed on a lot of requests, but it's a good way to do it without much fuss, and using DSNs with which you can specify much more than using function parameters.

**EDIT**:
You can define your own mssql_connect(), mssql_command(), etc, using ADO. That's a workaround if regular mssql extension won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the build in database wrapper PDO from php.

Here is some information about PDO: [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

And here is information on the use of MSSQL with PDO [MSSQL and PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)